# How can I set a dropdown whose id is equal to a CurrentApLevelIndex variable and option contains a CurrentLevel variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I set a dropdown whose id is equal to a CurrentApLevelIndex  variable and option contains a CurrentLevel variable in jquery?

```
var CurrentApLevelIndex = "ApLevelIndex";
var CurrentLevel = "11111";        

$("'#' + CurrentApLevelIndex  option[value = '" + CurrentLevel + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: "getfieldbyname" what is this?

Comment: and what is "rsTransInfo"? or "cf_2684248"? The numbers Mason, what do they mean??

Comment: Please don't worry about that. I am using an API and it is a way to get the value.

Comment: how about telling us what kind of API so we can understand what you are talking about...

Comment: My issue is in this line.  $("'#' + CurrentApLevelIndex  option[value = '" + CurrentLevel + "']").attr("selected", "selected");

Comment: i think you would want to rephrase your question, because it took me several tries to understand what your issue was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#" + CurrentApLevelIndex + " option[value='" + CurrentLevel + "']").prop("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score -1):

your selector should be changed to this:

```
$("#" + CurrentApLevelIndex + " option[value*='" + CurrentLevel + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/wtaxpaqp/)**</kbd>

the changes i've made:

- you put the `CurrentApLevelIndex` var as plain text, you need to refer to it as a variable.
- i added an asterix to the `value'`, and made it `[value*=` this searches for `CurrentLevel` as any possible substring of `value`

Comment: It doesn't work. I get an error. Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#'ApLevelIndex_1option[value* = '2']

Comment: He has extra quotes and is missing the space between ID and option.  Try my answer.

Comment: yep didnt notice, i've fixed it + added a fiddle example

Comment: All right, those comments were going nowhere productive, so I cleaned them up. Let's stay civil here.